# MIPS If Statement Being Ignored

Tags: if-statement, mips

I have a word array of 1's and 0's that is 7x5.  My code is supposed to branch whenever there's a 1 to display a certain graphic, however, I noticed that the statement is being ignored.  Here's the code:

bge s1, 5, _increment_outer_loop

la  a0, arena

mul t0, s0, 28     #i

mul t1, s1, 4      #j

add t1, t1, t0

add t2, a0, t1

beq t2, 1, _draw_arena

j   _increment_inner_loop

Can anyone shine light on the problem?  Thank you

Comment: You probably want to issue `lw $t2, $t2(0)` before your `beq` instruction to actually load the item from memory

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't seem to help.  There must be something wrong with other parts of my project.

Comment: There's not enough code here to reason over what the processor will do or about errors in the program.  "I noticed that the statement is being ignored" can you be more specific?  Processors don't honor some things and ignore others *except as instructed to do so by the program*.

Comment: Cannot comment on that as you did not post enough code. I am fairly certain you did need to load the item from memory using lw as commented before

Comment: When you single step the program, verify that each and every instruction has the effect you want.  Here as @gusbro is pointing out, you appear to be comparing a pointer (aka memory address) in `$t2`,  to the integer value 1.  Generally, such a comparison is meaningless, so you're probably missing a memory access.